# Unable to send notification to all connection through SSE

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to notify all the users of an event through server sent event but don't know why but its not working. I am able to notify single user if i use queue but if i change the configuration to use topic it does nothing. A you see below i am use queue and comment out template.setPubSubDomain(true) in jmsTopicTemplate then it is sending to single user

```
@Bean
    public Publisher<Message<LocationData>> jmsReactiveSource(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .destination(JMSConfig.Location_TOPIC).
                        jmsMessageConverter(messageConverter()))
                //.channel(new PublishSubscribeChannel(executor()))                 
//              .channel(MessageChannels.flux())
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                .toReactivePublisher();
    }
```

You can check the code at https://github.com/haiderali22/spring-tracking-jms-sse-mongo-app

Comment: Cloning your repo... Thank you for such a great sample!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have  checked your project unfortunately it is still big enough to digest properly.
But what I see from Integration perspective should be like this:

```
return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .destination(JMSConfig.Location_TOPIC).
                            jmsMessageConverter(messageConverter())
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .id("jmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter"))
            .toReactivePublisher();
```

The `toReactivePublisher()` injects the channel by itself already. No need in any other in between. The `autoStartup(false)` is for deferred subscription into the final `Flux`. This way you won't pull messages from JMS until a subscription happens to the `Flux` in the end.

The `.id("jmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter"))` you will use later in the `LocationService` for this:

```
public Flux<LocationData> watch() {
    return Flux.from(jmsReactiveSource)
            .map(Message::getPayload)
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> jmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.start());
}
```

This way you won't start pulling from JMS until a real subscription happens into a `Flux`.

The JMS topic has no relevance to this SSE subject.

If you can make your project more simpler, I would try it again.
I'm not familiar with Lombok though...

**UPDATE**

With the current solution you need to make it like this:

```
.channel(MessageChannels.flux())
.toReactivePublisher();
```

The problem that with regular `.toReactivePublisher()` just after that message-driven we get only one-subscriber for the final publisher.

to make it pub-sub you definitely need to place a `FluxMessageChannel` in between. This way all your SEE are going to be sent to all the JavaScript subscribers.

Comment: thank you for taking your time in answering the question. I included project lombok for just generating constructor, setters/getters and builder pattern . Will try the changes you suggestion

Comment: I have tried the changes you suggested but still it does not work  , also updated the github with that . Again if i comment the line in JMSConfig template.setPubSubDomain(true);  It started randomly sending messaes to only one user , I also added an html in http://localhost:8080/test , you can send the request using http://localhost:8080/location/push?id=54545&lat=33.33&lng=77.55

Comment: By simpler you mean remove project lombok?

Comment: No, you can leave Lombok, not a big deal. I mean your project has a complicated structure. And I need to understand how to produce message to JMS so all my SSE subscribers are good to go.

Comment: Please, make it working with plain strings. It is too hard figure out what should I send to the app...

Comment: done pleas check now the request will be http://localhost:8080/location/push?data=t4 and please uncomment the line  template.setPubSubDomain(true);

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.